# jQuery get text in element but ignore style tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have javascript code that tests if a div has some non whitespace text content.

This works but it cannot differentiate between text content or style tag declarations within the div and the test fails when there is no text content but a style tag with css data.

Question is how to test for empty text content while ignoring the style tag?

HTML:

```
<div id='test1'>
    <div>   </div>
</div>

<div id='test2'>
    <div>   </div>

<style>
.style1{
    border:1px;    
}        
</style>    

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Works
if($('#test1').text().trim().length==0){
    alert('test1 has no content!');
}    

// Does not work due to style1 declaration within style tag within div
if($('#test2').text().trim().length==0){
    alert('test2 has no content!');
}
```

Test URL: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sLDWB/

Comment: You could copy the node, then remove style tags, and then check. (To throw an idea out there)  http://jsfiddle.net/sLDWB/3/ (There must be better answers though)

Comment: Get the inner html and remove tags which you don't want to consider.

Comment: A `style` tag in the `body` won't validate; it's technically not correct (unless it's HTML5 scoped)

Comment: @elclanrs You sure about that?

Comment: Pretty sure, at least in HTML4, but there's no point in putting it in the body, you gain nothing, you lose a few ms of unstyled content, so it's basically useless. Only scoped styles make sense in the body as they apply to the parent element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is cloning the element and removing the `style` tags:

```
$.fn.isTextless = function() {
   var txt = this.first()
                 .clone()
                 .find('style')
                 .remove()
                 .end()
                 .text();

   return $.trim(txt).length === 0; 
}

if ( $('#test2').isTextless() ) {
    alert('test2 has no content!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Z3M4/

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a common class for all the elements you need to check, loop through them using `each`, store the initial HTML, remove the style tag, do your check and restore the initial HTML. Like so :

```
$('.testdiv').each(function() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).find('style').remove();

    if($(this).text().trim().length==0){
        alert( $(this).attr('id') + ' has no content!');
    } 
    $(this).html(divHtml);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLDWB/1/

Answer (score 1):

`Subtract` the `style` tag's length with the actual length.

Try,

```
if($('#test1').text().trim().length==0){
    alert('test1 has no content!');
}    

if($('#test2').text().trim().length - $('#test2 style').text().trim().length ==0){
    alert('test2 has no content!');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/sLDWB/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following javascript code

```
document.getElementById('test2').innerText
```

Answer (score -1):

The style tag is meant to go in the head of a page. Why do you even have `.style1` there if no element uses `style1`? If you want to change the style of a div, either do `<div style="border: 1px;">` or make a style declaration in the `<head>` part of the HTML page.

In short, you shouldn't ever have a `<style>` tag outside of `<head>`.